# Bit shift when there is no ... bit shift operator

Tags: vbscript, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I have to implement a checksum (CRC16 CCITT) to verify the content of a file. 
The checksum is rather simple to implement in C or Java thanks to << and >> operators and the many examples available on the net.

The thing is... my checksum computation has to be implemented in VBScript.

My experience with this language is nearly null but from my understanding, there isn't anything provided to do bit shifting in VBScript. Therefore I rely on **multiplications and divisions by two.** It works well except with **negative values**.

I ran few tests and I believe that VBScript handles its 16 bits integers with two's complement.

**Q1:** can someone confirm me this (two's complement in VBScript) ? I didn't find any precise information from MSDN website.

**Q2:** Is it possible to do a bit shift (right and left) with simple mathematical operations when the negative number is coded with two's complement ?

.

Thanks a lot, I'd really like to avoid a kludge like dealing with integers as arrays of '1' and '0' or calling some java / c app from VBScript.

**EDIT** thank you for the help, find below my implementation of a right shift in VBScript:

```
Function rightShift(value,bits)
    Dim res

    res = 65535 AND value

    If value>=0 Then
       res = res \ (2^bits)
    Else If value=-1 Then
             res = rightShift(res + 32768, bits - 1)
         Else
             res = rightShift(value \ 2 + 32768, bits - 1)
         End If
    End If

    rightShift = res AND 65535
End Function
```

Note about the code above: value was sometimes exceeding the 16 bits therefore I had to mask the unused bits to avoid overflow (`AND 65535`).

Comment: Thank you so much for handing out your code! I needed the exact same thing except for 32 bits, which was easy to do with your code. :) I am implementing CRC32. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In two's-complement arithmetic, the only impact that negative values have occurs when dividing by 2 to shift right: the intended right shift will take place, but it will also introduce a new 1-bit in the most significant bit (MSB) position to "keep the value negative" -- unless the original value was -1, in which case all bits become 0.  So to correct for this, try the following pseudocode:

```
rightshift(x) {
    if x >= 0 return x / 2;
    if x < -1 return x / 2 - MINVAL;    # Strip out sign bit
    # x must be -1, i.e. "all bits on"
    return x - MINVAL;
}
```

`MINVAL` should be the value whose representation consists of just the MSB on and all other bits off, which is -32768 for 16 bits.  (So named because it will be the most negative representable number using two's-complement.)  Interestingly, adding `MINVAL` works just as well as subtracting it in the above pseudocode, since in two's-complement arithmetic, `x - y` = `x + NOT(y) + 1`, and `MINVAL == NOT(MINVAL) + 1`.

Left shifts using multiply-by-2 work for negative numbers just as well as they do for positive ones.

Answer (score -1):

This is not answer but a comment. The answer given by @j_random_hacker worked for me. But in languages that perform integer divisions like C# (assuming you can't use the builtin right shift operator for whatever reason) one needs to round up when x is not even.

```
static int MINVAL = (int) -0x80000000;
    static int ShiftRight(int n,int bits)
    {
        //if (n >= 0) return n / (int)Math.Pow(2, bits);
        //double temp = n / Math.Pow(2, bits);
        //int r  = (int) Math.Floor(temp);
        //return r;
        if (n >= 0) return n / 2;
        if (n < -1) return (int)Math.Round(n / (double)2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) - MINVAL;//+ (n%2==0?0:-1);    // Strip out sign bit
        // x must be -1, i.e. "all bits on"
        return n - MINVAL;
    }
```

Now yes C# has a built-in shift operators so this is just education purpose.

Answer (score -1):

That is very slow, try this. The following works for values >= 0 but will 
throw an array subscript out of bounds for bitshifts > 14 bits and the code is:

```
dim ShiftArray
ShiftArray = Array(1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512,
1024,2048,4096, 8192, 16384)

' example usage
dim num
num = 17
num = num * ShiftArray(2) ' left shift 2 bits
num = num / ShiftArray(3) ' right shift 3 bits
```

Multiply by number of bits to shift for left shift. Divide for right shift.
This array works for 16-bit integers.

For 32-bit integers the array will thow out of bounds array subscript for bitshifts > 30 and is:

```
dim ShiftArray
ShiftArray = Array(1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024,   
2048,4096, 8192, 16384, 32768, 65536, 131072, 262144, 524288,
1048576, 2097152, 4194304, 8388608, 16777216, 33554432,
67108864, 134217728, 268435456,  536870912, 1073741824)
```